# Area 51: Can't commit. And I really really want to

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Every time I try click any of the various Commit! links/buttons, nothing happens.  I checked my profile, and they don't show up.  There appears to be a javascript error (Done, but with errors...) on the page.

I'm able to follow proposals successfully.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a trailing comma in one of our javascript objects in master.js, e.g.

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3, }
```

which IE7 was failing to parse.

It's fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: I don't think IE7 was correct; I think that's legal in Javascript, if I'm reading the spec right: `ObjectLiteral : { PropertyNameAndValueList , }`

Comment: @Michael Right.. I think it's legal in javascript but illegal in json? I'll play it safe and remove "(correctly)" from my answer.

Comment: all browsers are compatible, but some browsers are more compatible than others (and some even redefine compatibility).

Comment: Awesome!  For the record, yes, I'm using IE7.

Comment: @Gamecat IE9 is ultra compatible. Did you know it has about 4 compatibility modes? And Chrome and Firefox don't have any. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem in IE7. It still does not work. However, I was able to commit in Firefox. I would recommend trying a different browser if you are using IE7.